# How to change Vuetify v-icon color in css

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify `v-icon` usually takes its color with a class. In my case, I am trying to change its color with a css class `menu-icon` when my router link is active.

```
        <v-btn icon class="menu-btn">
            <router-link to="/client/dashboard">
                <v-icon class="menu-icon">
                    mdi-gauge-full
                </v-icon>
                <div class="menu-titles">Dashboard</div>
            </router-link>
        </v-btn>
```

```
    .router-link-active .menu-icon {
        color: #2F80ED ;
    }
```

The problem is `v-icon` does not seems to accept css color attribute. Is there a way to change it with css ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<v-icon>` uses the value of its CSS `color` property and maps it into the `fill` property of it's SVG children (using `fill="currentColor"`).

So you only need to set the `color` CSS value on `.v-icon`, and it will work:

Simple example:

```
<v-icon large>mdi-domain</v-icon>
```

In CSS:

```
i.v-icon.v-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

Working example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
i.v-icon.v-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-icon>mdi-domain</v-icon>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I advise against using `!important`.
By default, Vuetify sets the `color` of icons using a *`2 × class`* specificity (i.e: `.theme--light.v-icon`), so we need to use something slightly higher `i.v-icon.v-icon` ( *`1 × el + 2 × class`* ).

---

Obviously, if you want to do it inline you can always go with the ***anti-pattern*** of inline style:

```
<v-icon large style="color: red;">mdi-domain</v-icon>
```

Like any anti-pattern, it's ***not recommended***. But it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help

```
    <v-icon large color="green darken-2">mdi-domain</v-icon>
```

Or if you want to change color using internal css, you can add a style tag like this at the end.

```
<style lang="scss" >
.classname {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, didn't work putting the color's name, but it worked putting the  hexadecimal value:

```
<v-icon color="#933">mdi-close</v-icon>
```

Despite the fact that in the [documentation of the Vuetify icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/), you find that it works by putting the names. But is required put v-app tag in vue template. Let it start this way:

```
<template>
<v-app>        
<v-icon color="red">mdi-close</v-icon>
</v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: This should be the selected solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your css file:

```
.theme--light.v-icon,
.theme--dark.v-icon {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```